# Unable to find Audit specification when I try to create Server level audit

Tags: sql-server, logins, audit

I am trying to use 'SERVER_PRINCIPAL_CHANGE_GROUP' audit action on a SQL Server to capture the sp_addlogin events. But when I try to create a Server level audit using GUI, I am not seeing the Audit action type drop down when I try to create the audit. Any help on how to do this ? I just want to capture who added a server level login using the SQL Server audits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't troubleshoot pointing and clicking through a GUI, because we don't know exactly what you did or what you might have missed.

You need to create a server level audit (which is like a container for specific audit definitions) *and* a server level audit specification (which is the part that dictates the auditing).

I suggest looking at the documentation for examples using DDL (e.g. [`CREATE SERVER AUDIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280448.aspx) and [`CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280767.aspx)). This wasn't too hard to work out:

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT ServerAudit
TO FILE 
(
    FILEPATH = N'C:\temp\',
    MAXSIZE = 0 MB,
    MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647,
    RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000,
    ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE,
    AUDIT_GUID = '0da5fd7b-8218-486f-8641-c31465cae657'
);
GO

ALTER SERVER AUDIT [ServerAudit] WITH (STATE = ON);
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [AuditPrincipals]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [ServerAudit]
ADD (SERVER_PRINCIPAL_CHANGE_GROUP)
WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
```

So then I did this:

```
CREATE LOGIN floob WITH PASSWORD = 'blat', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

And I saw this in the audit log:

> [image]

Comment: I was able to create the audit suited to my requirements using the script but is there any reason why SERVER_PRINCIPAL_CHANGE_GROUP audit specification was not made visible through GUI ? Is that intentional by Microsoft or am I missing anything here?

Comment: @karun10 I still don't know where in the GUI you were looking. It will be on the audit specification dialog, not the audit dialog. Post a screen shot of where you are looking and expecting to find it - my guess is you are expecting a drop down on the audit dialog, but this isn't where it goes...

Comment: Yes. That's where I was looking at, the drop down in the audit specification. So, if we need to create a audit to capture the login information, the only way to do this is using the T-SQL, right ? We cannot do this from GUI I guess then.

Comment: @karun10 No, you can see it in the GUI ([evidence here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RiZVj.png)), again you need to clarify (maybe post a screen shot, like I did).